# ios/iphone/storyboard: Barbuttons on toolbar not displaying

Tags: iphone, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem

For some reason, the lower bar button items, Select All and Select None shown in the image from storyboard below are not displaying.  I copied this configuration from another app where it works fine.  Can't for the life of me figure out what could be the problem.  The upper buttons, Cancel and Done do display.  This VC is presented modally.

Has anyone seen this before or can you suggest what could be wrong?

The bar buttons are not outlets.  They are wired to action methods, however, since they do not display in the app, I can't tell if they work.

The other thing that is not working properly here is that the tableview is empty.  However, for now I'd be content to see the lower bar button items.  I've tried changing the table view size to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

storyboard:
[image: what it looks like in storyboard]

What displays on phone:
[image]

Comment: Found issue.  In nav controller in which VC is embedded, you have to check show Toolbar.